# Every set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}\;$ is isomorphic to some subset of $[a,b]\;$ for all $b>a$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to prove a more general theorem.

I know that for some ordinal $\alpha$ there exists an isomorphism between $\alpha$ and some $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}\;$

I want to show that for all $b>a\;$ I can find a subset of  $[a,b]\;$  such that $\alpha$ is isomorphic to that subset.

Comment: The ordinal $\alpha$ has to be countable. Suppose that $\alpha$ is uncountable. Let $f$ be the order preserving map from $\alpha$ to $\mathbb{R}$. For all ordinals $\beta < \alpha$ define $r_{\beta} = f(\beta + 1) - f(\beta) > 0$. But then, for some $\epsilon > 0$ there are uncountably many $\beta$ such that $r_{\beta} > \epsilon$. This contradicts the Archimedean property of the reals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an immediate consequence of having a strictly increasing embedding $f:(\Bbb R,\le)\hookrightarrow ([a,b],\le)$ in, say, $f(x)=a+\frac{b-a}\pi\operatorname{arccot}(-x)$

Comment: Thanks!
Could you maybe share some more examples?